# Flash webcam access request prompt unresponsive

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs4, webcam

I have a parent swf called Main.swf that loads a child Registration.swf via a regular loader class then adds it to the stage. This child has a webcam function that captures an image but before that happens it prompts the user for permission to allow the webcam to be turned on.

The problem I'm having is that in my IDE the prompt works like a charm and continues through to capturing image data. When I plop the files on a live server it fails.

A friend recommended that it's most likely an issue with how I'm requesting permission from the child, so instead I'm calling an event to the parent telling IT to prompt and still no luck. Having the same issues.

Note: The parent .swf was published as Player 9 and the child is in Player 10. I had to do it this way because each package has dependencies that require it.

I'm wondering what the heck I might be doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I ended up resolving the problem. It happened to be an issue with using swfobject in injecting the Flash element into the page. Apparently center aligning the div that contained it throws off the security policy box.