# Detect movement of HTML element caused by CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-transitions

I have a Flash element on my page, and because Flash is generally quite delicate it needs to be positioned at integer pixel values (see [Flash webcam access request prompt unresponsive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3107586/1180785) if you want details).

I'm achieving this by wrapping the `object` in a `div`, setting `position:absolute` on the `object`, and using jQuery to set `left` and `top` to the rounded `offset` of the containing `div`. That was a mouthful, here it is in code form:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <object id="flash" blah style="position:absolute">
        <!-- blah -->
    </object>
</div>
<script>
    function update(){
        var p=$('#wrapper').offset();
        $('#flash').css({'left':Math.round(p.left),'top':Math.round(p.top)});
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).resize(update);
        update();
    });
</script>
```

And that all works great (if the code above has a mistake, it's just from cutting it down)

That will update the position when the browser changes size, and it's easy enough to update it when the position is changed by some JavaScript, but the page also uses the CSS `transition-duration` to animate some changes. How can I detect this? At a minimum, I'd like to detect when a transition which effects the object is taking place, and know when it will stop. Ideally I'd like to know how to catch any movement (for example caused by font size changes or images loading).

Comment: there are some events concerning transitions, but I don't know how useful they are

Comment: You can detect when a transition has finished but still not detect when a transition start, at least not something i'm aware of. Search for transitionend event

Comment: @roasted thanks, that's a start. It at least ends up positioned correctly now. I'd still like to position it during the animation if possible. To future readers: `.on('transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend',update);`

Comment: So I guess there isn't an ideal solution. Maybe, before animating, you can use JS to detect if an CSS transition is set. And I don't know whether this applies to your situation, but maybe it's better to move the element using translate; [Paul Irish wrote a good article about this](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/).

Comment: @sroes translate doesn't apply, sadly. The whole point of this is to remove sub-pixel positioning, but translate supports sub-pixels and isn't smart enough to take an equation parameter (I'd need to translate by `floor(absolute_coord) - absolute_coord`).

Comment: try this  $(":animated")

Comment: @Fewtron nope: http://jsfiddle.net/RpP4r/

Comment: (also that wouldn't be an event-driven solution, which is what I'm looking for)

Answer (score 0):

Could you check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DpYNm/
It logs when a movement starts and ends, I'm not sure if it's the solution to your problem, but it just might help you in the right direction!

```
function checkForMove() {
if ($('#testDiv').prop('user_default_width') === undefined) {
    $('#testDiv').prop('user_default_width', $('#testDiv').width());
    $('#testDiv').prop('user_is_moving', false);
}

if ($('#testDiv').width() != $('#testDiv').prop('user_default_width') && !$('#testDiv').prop('user_is_moving')) {
    $('#log').html($('#log').html() + "Move started<br/>");
    $('#testDiv').prop('user_is_moving', true);
}
if ($('#testDiv').width() == $('#testDiv').prop('user_default_width') && $('#testDiv').prop('user_is_moving')) {
    $('#log').html($('#log').html() + "Move ended<br/>");
    $('#testDiv').prop('user_is_moving', false);
}

setTimeout(checkForMove, 1);
```

}

```
checkForMove();
```

The checkForMove is called every ms and in the first call it will save the width of the div to a property. Everytime it changes (start of transition) it will log and save a helper property to ensure it will not log again until the transition is back to the default size. I'm sure you can change that part to fit it to your needs! :)

Comment: Every millisecond?! Crikey! Anyway I know I can use an interval (you should use `setInterval` not `setTimeout` for things like this; timeout is wasteful), but I'm looking for an event-driven solution.

Comment: I don't think there is an event-driven solution. You can, however, increase the timeout, although 1ms is a lot of time for a cpu, even in javascript. About the difference between setTimeout and setInterval: these are essentially the same, but setInterval will execute exactly every x ms and the way I am using setTimeout means that only after the code in the timeout is done executing, the timer will start again. Afaik they internally use the same mechanism.